# How to display a certain webpage for a particular day of the week

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website that has a Radio schedule, Mon - Sun. I would like to be able to display the correct schedule page for the current day, how would I do this? The site is a standard html site. I would also like to be able to highlight the particular show depending on the time of day.

Any ideas, this is all new to me.

Regards

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's also in the javascript section I'll post a JS version of it:

```
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Weekend","Weekend"];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

window.location = days[n - 1]+".html";
```

place this at the top of your index.html file. In the same folder you need the various Monday.html ... Friday.html files

in the same way you could do:

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
```

and then add a class "current-show" to a specific element in the page (with jQuery)

```
$(".show-time-"+ h).addClass("current-show");
```

This assumes that you have given the right classes to the show in the page (for example

```
<div class="show-time-14"></div>
```

And then in your css you can do:

```
.current-show { background-color: #BADA55: }
```

Comment: Hi, The codes worked perfectly all week, but today, Sunday, its stopped working and its redirecting to the 404 page. Any ideas?

Comment: I set my computer's day to Sunday and run the script. I noticed that on Sundays the getDay() function returns 0. This means that for the computer the week starts on sundays and that's why it failed on sunday:
    days[n - 1] //returns undefined if n == 0

I think the following code should fix it:

var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

window.location = days[n]+".html";

Comment: Hi I am now trying to get the highlight hour function working, so far my code looks like this;

Comment: <!-- #5 Tuesday-->
    <div class="show-time-18">
    <div class="portfolio-one-house">
    <a class="picture" href="#" title="House"><img src="image/music_genre/house_100.png" alt="***" class="portfolio-one-house-left"></a>
      <h1>18:00 - 20:00 - DJ ***** (Alternate Weeks)</h1>
      <p><strong>*******</strong> -  </p>
      <a href="#write-comment" id="code" title="" class="middle-button" style="float:left; margin:-10px 0px 0px 4px;"><span class="middle-right"></span>Email DJ</a> </div></div>

Comment: I have added the code $(".show-time-"+ h).addClass("current-show");
to a separate file called class.js, with a link to it in the header, and have added the css to the main style sheet. The highlight does not work as I presume I have added this incorrectly. I apologies for my lack of knowledge, I am just about to start jquery & js at code academy.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you add the link to the js file to the bottom of the body (right before you close the <body> tag). That way it won't interrupt the loading of the page. Now to your script, I made a little demo on jsfiddle, There are 24 boxes (one for each hour) and the one corresponding to the current hour should have a red border.

If you import your css and js file correctly it should work.
To see if they're being loaded use the chrome developer tools, in the console tab, see if there are any errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/H7dC5/4/

Comment: worked a treat, Thank You so much!! I just need to mess around with the CSS file.

Comment: I'm using code academy to learn coding, but have not got to JS and javascript yet, but at least I can dissect this code to see how it works. A great learning curve.

Comment: JS is short for javascript so it's the same. Good luck with your learning and don't be afraid to ask the community. I also suggest http://css-tricks.com/ as a learning platform.
Have a nice day

Comment: Damn thought it was working, must be a CSS problem somewhere. The background colour works highlighting the different time slots, however the active border does not show up. I've even tried just using a different text colour. The example works perfect on jsfiddle. I'll keep trying the css.

Comment: When I take out the code you use to create the individual DIVs I need to add a 14 instead of the 0 to make it work <div class="single-show show-time-0">. Doing the same on my code does not work. Is the time taken from the server? As the site is US hosted.

Comment: No, the time is taken from the client. Do you have a link to a page where I can see your case?

Comment: This shows the schedule page. It auto selects the right day of the week as per your previous code. This does not have any of your latest code added.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have the following html documents:

```
Monday.html

...

Sunday.html
```

You can use the following code to output the page of the day:

```php
<?php

    $page = date('l') . '.html';
    readfile($page);
    exit(0);
?>
```

The example uses the function [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the day of the week as textual representation.

Place the code in file called `pageOfTheDay.php` in the **same** folder as the html documents on your webserver. In your HTML then use a link like

```
<a href="pageOfTheDay.php">Page of the day</a>
```

Note: The example assumes that you are using an english locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from a "[page controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html)", say `index.php`. This page is the only page the user loads and the actual HTML "page" is included automatically. This could be decided by a URL param or default to the current date.

An untested and very basic example of what I mean:

```
  <?php

    if (isset($_GET["day"])) {
      $day = $_GET["day"];
    } else {
      $day = date("l");
    }
    $fileName = $day . ".php";

    if (file_exists(realpath() . $fileName)) {
      include $fileName;
    }

  ?>
```

Note: I have renamed the `.HTML` files to `.PHP`, allowing them to be included (you don't actually need to have any PHP code within them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and quick response.